# What is the meaning of the first line in the song "Stand By You" by Rachel Platten?

Tags: lyrics, songs

> **Hands, put your empty hands in mine**
>   And scars, show me all the scars you hide
>   And hey, if your wings are broken
>   Please take mine so yours can open, too
>   'Cause I'm gonna stand by you

Does it mean to hold hands? 
P.S.: Just curious ;)

Link to [Video Song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwB9EMpW8eY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Empty handed* is an idiomatic expression for loss, as in "[to go (or come) away **empty handed**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+away+empty-handed)."

Here, the lyrics refer to someone wounded by personal loss, with metaphoric scars to hide and metaphoric broken wings.  The offer is to hold and thereby support and comfort.  Which means more than physically holding hands.

Answer (score -2):

I think it means, if you feel loss you can hold each other's hand. You can borrow the other's wing, and make yourself comfortable, because if you need, I'm going to stand by you. Don't be shy, don't feel so rude, I gave you what you want as belong as you with me.

Comment: Hi Riza, welcome to EL&U. NB: the system has flagged your post as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - and we also expect a reasonable standard of English (which I've mostly corrected for you). For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)